# How can I get from Krakow to Prague?

Tags: transportation, poland, czech-republic, prague, krakow

I am looking for transportation from Krakow to Prague.

The only requirement I have is that it's limited in time, so I can plan it. Hitch-hiking is not a possibility.
I don't care much about the transport, I would just appreciate that it excels in something (price, scenery, time, etc.)
Of course affordability is important, so renting a private jet or something like that is not an option.

Comment: Take the train.  I'd do an answer, but I don't have Polish train tables in front of me :)  Oh - And go through Katowice and Breslau (Wroclaw) to get there

Comment: I'd also suggest taking the train.

Comment: Depends on your full itinerary. On a trip that went USA-Budapest by air and return Prague-USA by air, with Budapest to Krakow in between by (some) train and (mostly) bicycle, the triangle ticket adding a flight Krakow to Budapest added about $10 to the ticket. Standalone it was very expensive.

Answer (score 12):

After somebody mentioned Rome2Rio.com on another question, I've gotten a lot of great use out of it.  It doesn't demand a date from you, and it's not limited to air.  It will combine all sorts of transportation to give you different options and different prices.

http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Krakow/Prague

**However**, sometimes it tells me I can go from A to B for a hundred dollars when everyone else says three hundred.  Ask Rome2Rio for details and it asks what day you want to go.  And it won't accept my answer which is, "Whatever day is a hundred dollars!"

Comment: My experience is that Rome2Rio is highly unreliable and has very poor coverage. There is almost always a better and cheaper option.

Comment: And if your destination is "Europe" R2R substitutes some point in Germany.  I never let it choose for me.  It's just one of many things I consult.

Answer (score 7):

I'd say take the train, from [this site](http://czech-transport.com/index.php?id=596):

> There is only 1 direct train between Krakow (Poland) and Prague (Czech rep.) and it goes overnight. It is also possible to go to Katowice (PL) or to Bohumín and there change to the train to Prague.
>
> TLK 402 Silesia, dep 22:03, Arr: 07:37. 45€ seat, 55€ couchette / bed.
>
> Schedule valid from 2013-12-15 to 2014-12-14

That's a six bed couchette, further down it has prices for other options. Most expensive looks like a single room deal at 96 Euro. I've taken a similar train in normal seats, it's not too bad but given that it's overnight you're saving the price of a hotel so factor that in.

That page also recommends the bus, details on [this page](http://czech-transport.com/index.php?id=9460). But honestly, unless timing is critical or you really need cheap as can be I'd take the train.

You can book tickets online or any travel agent or someone at the bus station there will be able to help you

Seat61.com has some more info on [this page](http://www.seat61.com/Poland.htm#Krakow) including some other ticket buying options.

Also, a word of warning, I haven't taken that specific train but have attempted to take a different train bound for Krakow. What I didn't notice is that some point in the middle of the night the train split and each half went different places ... so I woke up in Warsaw. So, just check if there's a specific part of the train you need to be on.

Answer (score 3):

The current situation is [documented in another answer on this site](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30507/where-to-buy-an-electronic-ticket-for-the-train-from-krakow-to-prague/89107#89107).

You may buy a direct sleeper train at [Intercity Poland](http://www.intercity.pl).

Or you can buy bus+train connections at http://www.le.cz or https://jizdenky.regiojet.cz

Answer (score 2):

There are trains from Krakow to Prague that run over night. They leave around 10 PM and arrive at 6 or 7 AM. There are 6 such trains on weekdays. One is direct and takes 9:20 minutes. The others use one or two connection although they run faster so arrive a little earlier. You won't see much since it's a night train but you do save one night of hotel.

There have more bus options, with 7 departures between midnight 00:30 and 23:50. If you want to see the scenery, you can travel entirely during the day, leaving at 10:30 and arriving at 18:25. Tickets cost from 23 to 38 Euros. They can be purchased in advance from [GetByBus](https://getbybus.com/en/) which I have used often.