# Where to buy an electronic ticket for the train from Krakow to Prague?

Tags: trains, tickets, prague, krakow

I know a direct train exists (it was [answered here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/28881/how-can-i-get-from-krakow-to-prague)). I tried to buy it via the polish rail and via the Czech rail but without success. How can I buy an electronic ticket for this  connection?

Comment: Did you try following the [Seat 61 instructions on booking Krakow to Prague tickets from abroad](http://seat61.com/international-trains/trains-from-Krakow.htm#Krakow_to_Prague)? Only those look fairly detailed on the options and pricing!

Comment: @Gagravarr I tried that but it wasnt possible to book.

Comment: Which thing(s) from the Seat 61 suggestions list did you try? (There are several). How far did you get with each? What problems did you face along the way?

Comment: http://booking.polrail.com/ Tried this website.

Comment: What did you try? How far did you get? What problems did you face along the way? What errors? What issues? Just as with things like StackOverflow, full details helps a lot!

Comment: Are you looking to book online and print out your ticket, or are you happy to book online and pickup your tickets?

Comment: at this moment I am perfectly happy with picking the tickets (if in Krakow)

Comment: You can book your ticket using http://booking.polrail.com and pickup in Krakow. What problems are you having using the polrail site? I did this exact route last week so I can detail the steps if that will answer your question.

Comment: @CraigCurtis I am getting price "0" and therefor I can't buy. There seems to be an error. I am aiming at the night train by the way.

Comment: I think you're entering the wrong value into the textbox labeled "Passenger 1. Age: ". If you enter "1" into it you'll see every fare listed as 0 PLN. You need to enter your actual age.

Comment: Damn, I'd totally buy that ticket for a price of "0". =P

Comment: @nsn Could you please add all this to the question and not only in comments?

Comment: You might check if [the site of the Deutsche Bahn](http://www.bahn.de ) will sell you tickets.

Answer (score 4):

I have been looking for all possible options and luckily I could find something. Please double check but I notice this site:

http://speciale-aanbiedingen.nl.voyages-sncf.com/nl/start-verkoop?prex=T_AFF_520B5C23D5C9A&ectrans=1

You can book your ticket and it should cost 72.40 euros and 8 hours+ travel time. From Kwakow to Prague. On this site you can change the language settings to UK English. Please note that if you do that the price will be quoted in Pound Sterling and that not all destinations are available. Only the most common.

[image: Europe Train Booking Site]

Comment: When Voyages-SNCF quotes prices in pounds, they're usually well above the normal price, in my experience. Does the price in pounds match the price in euros in this case? And does the price in euros quoted by Voyages-SNCF match the normal ticket price that you'd pay in Poland or the Czech Republic?

Answer (score 2):

There is a night train operated by flag carriers PKP Intercity and České dráhy (ČD / Czech Railways). That is available for booking at [www.intercity.pl](https://www.intercity.pl) or at station.

LEO Express runs buses across border connecting to their trains to Prague. You may want to book that trip online at [www.le.cz](https://www.le.cz).

The same model (bus + train) uses RegioJet, and sells online at [jizdenky.regiojet.cz](https://jizdenky.regiojet.cz)